# Why can't I use short circuit logical operators on vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

FD is an excel file, A is the data from FD column 5. (Each cell of column 5 include 1, 2 or 3)

If the cell in column 5 in FD include 2 or 3, then ...
else if the cell in column 5 in FD include 1 or 3 then ..
...
elseif all cell in column 5 include 1 only, then ..
...

A = FD (:,5);
C = 3x3 matrix

```
If A == 2 || A == 3
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
elseif A == 1 || A == 3
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
elseif A == 1 || A == 2
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
elseif A == 1
   Avg = C(1,1)/sum(sum(C));
elseif A == 2
   Avg = C(2,2)/sum(sum(C));
elseif A == 3
   Avg = C(3,3)/sum(sum(C));
else
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C,2))/3;
end
```

However, there is error with the above code. ??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Does anyone can help?

Comment: What error do you get? What does `A=FD(:,5)` mean? (what's FD? is A a single number or a vector?) Also, it looks like the last 4 `elseif` statements will never be reached, because they're covered in the first two ( If `A` is 1,2, or 3 then at least one of the following will be true: `if A==2||A==3` and `elseif A==1||A==3`, meaning that your `elseif A==1`, `elseif A==2`, `elseif A==3` will never be reached...

Comment: @mathematical.coffee, just edited the question. yes, the elseif A==1...can not be reached..so..how am i going to modified it?

Comment: Learn to use `all()` and `any()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short-cut operators only apply to scalar quantities. The point of the short-cut operators is that the RHS is not evaluated unless it needs to be. So in the following example, the `A==2` is never evaluated:

```
A = 1;
I = A == 1 && A == 2
```

With that in mind, what should the following do?

```
A = [1 3]
I = A == 1 && A == 2;
```

Furthermore, if-clauses ought to have scalar conditions. What should this code do?

```
if [true false], disp('true'), else disp('false'), end
```

You probably want `all` or `any` to combine the vector elements.

In any case, I think you also have your if-clauses in the wrong order. Try:

```
if all(A == 1)
   Avg = C(1,1)/sum(sum(C));
elseif all(A == 2)
   Avg = C(2,2)/sum(sum(C));
elseif all(A == 3)
   Avg = C(3,3)/sum(sum(C));
elseIf all(A == 2 | A == 3)
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
elseif all(A == 1 | A == 3)
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
elseif all(A == 1 | A == 2)
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C+eps,2))/2;
else
   Avg = sum(diag(C)./sum(C,2))/3;
end
```

Comment: In `I = A == 1 && A == 2`, the second part `A == 2` is definitely evaluated.  The shortcut operator for `&&` (AND) works only if the first argument evaluates to `false`.  However, the second argument in an `||` (OR) statement is not evaluated is the first one evaluates to `true`, as in `I = A == 1 || A == 2`.

Comment: When `A = [1 2]`, is `A == 1` equal to `true` or is it equal to `false`?

Comment: My comment above refers to the top example given in this answer: "So in the following example, the `A==2` is never evaluated: `A = 1; I = A == 1 && A == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the short-circuit operations on arrays in matlab.
That is quite logcial, if you think about it. Short circuit operators stop the calculation if the first operand causes the expression to be true/false regardless of another operands. But this can't be true in vectors.

So, try using "|" and "&" instead of "||" and "&&"

Comment: @rock, Please up-vote for my answer and accept it if it helped you.